# Pagination - Automated Loop Through HTML Table Rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a working HTML page(not my expertise), I mainly do ERP but this is a custom addition I am working on. I am populating data in an HTML table with a preprocessor(ERP). When I am writing the HTML file, in another program, I am currently padding the table top/bottom. In the Javascript, I am currenty auto refreshing, and auto scrolling.

I want to switch to use Pagination( Table Only) and limit the number of rows shown per page to 30. I still want to autorefresh, but ONLY after it has hit the last set of Rows in the table. Every example I have looked for shows examples using "Navigation", I do NOT want to do that. I want to automate it, kind of like looping through flight times at the airport by page.

I could really use some help. Below is my code.

```
$(window).load( function() {
        var iWidth = $(document).width()*0.055-getScrollBarWidth();
        var iCellWidth = ($(document).width() - ($(document).width()*0.05-    iWidth))/13;

        $(".data-cell").css("width",iCellWidth+"px");
        $(".red-cells").css("width",iCellWidth+"px");
        $(".orange-cells").css("width",iCellWidth+"px");
        $(".yellow-cells").css("width",iCellWidth+"px");
        $(".mist-cells").css("width",iCellWidth+"px");
        $(".blue-cells").css("width",iCellWidth+"px");
        $(".gray-cells").css("width",iCellWidth+"px");
        $(".cyan-cells").css("width",iCellWidth+"px");
        $(".magenta-cells").css("width",iCellWidth+"px");
        $( ".TFtable tr td:nth-last-child(1)" ).css("width",iWidth+"px");

        pageScroll();
    });

    function getScrollBarWidth () {
        var inner = document.createElement('p');
        inner.style.width = "100%";
        inner.style.height = "200px";

        var outer = document.createElement('div');
        outer.style.position = "absolute";
        outer.style.top = "0px";
        outer.style.left = "0px";
        outer.style.visibility = "hidden";
        outer.style.width = "200px";
        outer.style.height = "150px";
        outer.style.overflow = "hidden";
        outer.appendChild (inner);

        document.body.appendChild (outer);
        var w1 = inner.offsetWidth;
        outer.style.overflow = 'scroll';
        var w2 = inner.offsetWidth;
        if (w1 == w2) w2 = outer.clientWidth;

        document.body.removeChild (outer);

        return (w1 - w2);
    };

    function pageScroll() {
        window.setInterval(function() {
        var elem = document.getElementById('MainDiv');
        var oldTop = elem.scrollTop;

        elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollTop+1;

        if(elem.scrollTop==oldTop)
            elem.scrollTop=0;
        }, 100);
    }
     setTimeout(function () { location.reload(1); }, 600000);
```

Comment: so? What's wrong with it? What console errors are you getting?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with my current code, I just want to change the page to use pagination, instead of auto scrolling.

Comment: Could this be a accomplished better using a plugin? The only examples I can find our dependant on using a navigation bar for the pages. I want to automate it.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed it to where I am creating separate HTML files controlling the table row limit with a wildcard, and then setTimeOut with window.location pointing to the next page. Also controlling the milliseconds for the setTimeOUT with a wildcard.

New version, commented out scrolling and just passing values in place of wildcards for the milliseconds, along with the location path to the next page. It loops through perfectly. Still NOT as clean as the table pagination examples I've seen.

```
/*      function pageScroll() {
        window.setInterval(function() {
        var elem = document.getElementById('MainDiv');
        var oldTop = elem.scrollTop;

        elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollTop+1;

        if(elem.scrollTop==oldTop)
            elem.scrollTop=0;
        }, 100);
    } */
     //setTimeout(function () { location.reload(1); }, 600000);
            //this section of JS will sleep for a set # of minutes, then redirect to next page, sleep time and redirect path controlled in GAB
    //sleep and redirect
    setTimeout(function () { window.location = "#redirect" }, #sleep);
```